# jQuery re-showing a div after hidden code

Tags: jquery, css

this is an update to a preview code question that was fix. What I'm doing now is adding a second click linkable `li` to hide **mykadd** div and re-show mykink.

here is a sample of what i'm trying to do...  http://jsfiddle.net/eWtaz/1/ it kind of works but its buggy

```
<li id="myklnk2">Show Main System</li>
<li id="myklnk1">Un/Select system</li>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".mykadd").hide();    
    $("#myklnk2").on("click", function(){
        $(".mykink, .mykadd").slideToggle();

    $("#myklnk1").on("click", function(){
        $(".mykadd, .mykink").slideToggle();
    });
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just fix the position of your closure  `});`

### *[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eWtaz/2/)*

```
$("#myklnk2").on("click", function(){
    $(".mykink, .mykadd").slideToggle();
});   // put it here

$("#myklnk1").on("click", function(){
    $(".mykadd, .mykink").slideToggle();   
});
// not here
```

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just do this?

```
<li id="myklnk2">Show Main System</li>
<li id="myklnk1">Un/Select system</li>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".mykadd").hide();    
    $("#myklnk2").on("click", function(){
        $(".mykink").slideUp();
        $(".mykadd").slideDown();
    });
    $("#myklnk1").on("click", function(){
        $(".mykadd").slideUp();
        $(".mykink").slideDown();
    });
});
</script>
```

Also the way you have it now, the $("#myklnk1") click event is nested inside of the $("#myklnk2") click event.

Answer (score 1):

`})` is on the wrong position.
Other thing you can do is select both `li` to bind an event and use `display: none` instead.

**html**

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("#myklnk2, #myklnk1").on("click", function(){
        $(".mykink, .mykadd").slideToggle();
    });
});​
```

**css**

```
.mykadd {
    display: none;
}
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/eWtaz/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Don't attach your second click event inside the first click handler because that happens before the event gets propagated, which triggers your second click.